# Bings Ads Api Python to get all campaigns for an account

Tags: python-3.x, bing-ads-api

I am struggling with bings api python to get all campaign.

```
ALL_CAMPAIGN_TYPES = ['Audience DynamicSearchAds Search Shopping']

 authorization_data = AuthorizationData(
        account_id=None,
        customer_id=None,
        developer_token=env('DEVELOPER_TOKEN'),
        authentication=None,
    )
    campaign_service = ServiceClient(
        service='CampaignManagementService',
        version=13,
        authorization_data=authorization_data,
        environment=env('ENVIRONMENT'),
    )
 campaigns = campaign_service.GetCampaignsByAccountId(
        AccountId="xxxxxxx", CampaignType=ALL_CAMPAIGN_TYPES)
```

it gives me error:
suds.WebFault: Server raised fault: 'Invalid client data. Check the SOAP fault details for more information. TrackingId: 1ee709e5-b0d5-4b82-a19e-65001a80789e.

Please help me to get rid out this.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a minimal example:

```
from bingads import (
    AuthorizationData,
    OAuthAuthorization,
    OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant,
    ServiceClient,
)

oauth_web_auth_code_grant = OAuthWebAuthCodeGrant(
    client_id="YOURCLIENTID",
    client_secret="YOURCLIENTSECRET",
    redirection_uri=None,
)
refresh_token = "SOMEREFRESHTOKEN"
oauth_tokens = oauth_web_auth_code_grant.request_oauth_tokens_by_refresh_token(
    refresh_token
)

authorization_data = AuthorizationData(
    developer_token="YOURDEVELOPERTOKEN",
    authentication=OAuthAuthorization(
        client_id=oauth_web_auth_code_grant.client_id,
        oauth_tokens=oauth_tokens,
    ),
)

customermanagement_service = ServiceClient(
    "CustomerManagementService",
    version=13,
    authorization_data=authorization_data,
)

get_user_response = customermanagement_service.GetUser(UserId=None)
user = get_user_response.User
```

You are missing `authentication` in `AuthorizationData`